# Commenting or annotating a function

Tags: python

According to the [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) you can do comments to annotate a function like this:

```
def comment():
    num: int = 5
    print ('COMMENTS', __annotations__)
```

Why doesn't this work then?

```
>>> comment()
COMMENTS {}
```

Comment: Those aren't comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the PEP you linked, you will find the following text:

> Annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to treat it as a local, even if it was never assigned to. **Annotations for local variables will not be evaluated**:
>
> ```
> def f():
>     x: NonexistentName  # No error.
> ```
>
> However, if it is at a module or class level, then the type will be evaluated:
>
> ```
> x: NonexistentName  # Error!
> class X:
>     var: NonexistentName  # Error!
> ```
>
> In addition, **at the module or class level**, if the item being annotated is a simple name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of that module or class (mangled if private) as an ordered mapping from names to evaluated annotations. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> from typing import Dict
> class Player:
>     ...
> players: Dict[str, Player]
> __points: int
>
> print(__annotations__)
> # prints: {'players': typing.Dict[str, __main__.Player],
> #          '_Player__points': <class 'int'>}
> ```

Local variable annotations are not evaluated and are not stored in an `__annotations__` dict. There are no `__annotations__` dicts for local variables at all, in fact; you're printing the `__annotations__` for the module globals.

Comment: cool, so in order to get the annotation within the function scope it would need to be put in the arguments of the function itself?

Comment: @Kyle: It doesn't make sense to change a function's arguments just to change the annotation behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You should read the full text of [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations) (emphasis mine):

> Note that if annotations are not found statically, then the `__annotations__` dictionary is not created at all. Also the value of having annotations available locally does not offset the cost of having to create and populate the annotations dictionary on every function call. **Therefore annotations at function level are not evaluated and not stored.**

Answer (score -1):

From [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/):

> Annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to treat it as a local, even if it was never assigned to. Annotations for local variables will not be evaluated.

And

> Note that if annotations are not found statically, then the **annotations** dictionary is not created at all. Also the value of having annotations available locally does not offset the cost of having to create and populate the annotations dictionary on every function call. Therefore annotations at function level are not evaluated and not stored.